# How do I use a nested loops and the function split() to create a list letter counter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble understanding why this program doesn't work. Of what I know so far is it's caused either by the nested loops or the function split().

```
letters = "abcd"
alphabet = "abcd"

counter = [0,0,0,0]

n = 0
splitAlpha = alphabet.split()
for letter in splitAlpha:
    for key in letters:
        if key == letter:
            counter[n] +=1
            n+=1

print(counter)
```

Comment: Well.. Your usage of `n` is a bit wrong. You could better get the index of a given letter in `letters` and update that in `counter`/

Comment: split method isn't for splitting words? by default it looks for space separators

Comment: `alphabet.split()` creates a list with a single element which is not what you want there. leave it out and use `alphabet` directly in your outer `for` loop.

Comment: You need to increment n in the upper loop.

Comment: `[alphabet.count(e) for e in letters]`

Comment: @dawg +1 but he wants to know why his code doesn't work

Comment: @Jérôme Ye thats what i meant but i still thank you guys a lot for sharing ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `alphabet.split()` as it return's you a list `["abcd"]` which is not relevant for your need.

```
letters = "abcd"
alphabet = "aacd"

counter = []

for i, l in enumerate(letters):
    counter.append(alphabet.count(l))


print(counter)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: If I understand him correctly he wants count of `a` in `counter[0]`, `b` in `counter[1]`, etc. Your example won't work really if `letters` will have more than 1 occurrence.

Comment: yee it doesnt work if the letters repeat ;/ but i was excited for a second :D

Comment: @favoretti, Thanks for the comment, I wasn't quite sure I understood the OP intention. I've fixed my code at the answer.

Comment: @omri_saadon cheers :) I got a bit rusty on `enumerate()` while writing an example for him, went with `alphabet.index(letter)` approach, but yours is neater :)

Comment: @Ivan , If your intention is as favoretti wrote, you can solve it much easily you can see in my updated answer

Comment: Btw, ditch the `n = 0` as well, as it's not required anymore.

Comment: Yep Thank you guys ! :D

Comment: Aaand. Your example won't work with the data I provided in mine (i.e. string contains letters that don't exist in `alphabet`). :P (sorry, getting a bit too pedantic)

Comment: Oh dear you guys ... haha i finally think that the problem is solved and Boom another problem haha :D Thanks for helping me! Much appreciated

Comment: @favoretti , lol, why not? count return's 0 in case it does not exist.

Comment: @omri_saadon `counter[i] = alphabet.count(l) IndexError: list assignment index out of range` :(

Comment: If the length of the 'alphabet' is less than the length of the 'letters' it will show an error

Comment: Ok, Ok.. So it's preffered that the counter will grow dynamically. I've updated the answer, I think this would pass your test :) @favoretti

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, here's another way to go about it:

```
letters = "abcdabcdabcdaz"
alphabet = "abcd"

counter = [0,0,0,0]

for letter in letters:
    try:
        counter[alphabet.index(letter)] +=1
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(counter)
```

`<list>.index(<element>)` will give you position of a wanted element in the list (or `ValueError`) if not found. By catching (and ignoring) the exception you skip incrementing the counters for non-existing letters of your `alphabet` definition.

Comment: Thank you ! :D if i could give a green tick thing to both of your answers i would :D

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, maybe try out the list function (splits words into an array):

```
letters = "abcd"
alphabet = "abcd"

counter = [0,0,0,0]

n = 0
splitAlpha = list(alphabet)
for letter in splitAlpha:
    for key in letters:
        if key == letter:
            counter[n] +=1
            n+=1

print(counter)
```

This program outputs

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```